# Populate two select box's with an array of Options?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an array that I would like to use to populate two different select box's but I'm seeing some weird behavior.  Populating the first select works fine but when adding the same list to the second select box, the first select is cleared and the last item is selected on the second select box.

```
var optionList = []

optionList.push(new Option("waba", "waba"))
optionList.push(new Option("shaba", "shaba"))

$('#first_select').html(optionList); //works fine
$('#second_select').html(optionList); //clears first select and last item is selected
```

[JS Fiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/mpautzke/tcuow32f/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to clone the optionList

```
var optionList = []

optionList.push(new Option("waba", "waba"))
optionList.push(new Option("shaba", "shaba"))

$('#first').html(optionList);
$('#second').html($(optionList).clone());
```

Answer (score 3):

set the html content for both in one statement:

```
$('#first, #second').html(optionList);
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tcuow32f/1/

Comment: I like this answer, but won't work easily in my situation.

Answer (score 1):

You have to clone them using `jQuery.clone` like this:

```
$('#first').html(optionList); // append the original options
$('#second').html($(optionList).clone()); // clone them and append the cloned ones
```